# Counting with decimal digits

Tags: combinatorics, functions

How many distinct ways are there to encode the decimal digits $0-9$ as binary sequences of length $4$? Consider only codes which represent different digits by different sequences.

Firstly, I could not understand mathematically what is asked for, whether it is string of length = $4$ which uses decimal digits, or it is something different. Moreover, what does it mean by saying "codes which represent different digits"? Aren't constructed string different with each other?

Comment: What do you mean by a binary sequence of decimal digits?

Comment: I posted this question mainly because given condition was also somehow vague for me as well.

Comment: I'm quite certain the OP means simply binary sequences of length $4$.  The obvious representation is $0 \to 0000$, $1 \to 0001$, $2 \to 0010$, etc., but of course there are others.

Comment: I asked this question maybe other users will know what does exactly mean "binary sequence of decimal digits"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yeah, because there is no other understanding besides that definition

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If we use your definition, then how many ways there will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $16$ binary strings of length $4$, ranging from $0000$ to $1111$. A code that represents each of the $10$ decimal digits $0-9$ with a different binary sequence of length $4$ can therefore be concocted in any of

$$16\times15\times14\times\cdots\times7$$

ways.  That is, you pick one of the $16$ binary strings to represent the decimal digit $0$, one of the $15$ *remaining* strings to represent the decimal digit $1$, one of the $14$ remaining strings for the decimal digit $2$, and so on up to $7$ choices for the decimal digit $9$. (Note, there will be six binary strings left over.)

Comment: Ah, I see John Douma said essentially the same thing a few minutes earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^4=16$ binary strings of length $4$ and there are $10$ digits so there are $16$ ways to encode $0$ and given an encoding for $0$ there are $15$ ways to encode $1$ etc. so we get the number of permutations of ten things out of sixteen things are the possible encodings.